# Comparing 2 query result in a query PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering if it's possible to compare 2 query result into one in PostgreSQL.
For example: I have this data on the whole month of March then i have another data for the whole month of april.

This query is the one I'm using to get the data on the month of March:

```
    SELECT availability_date, ROUND(AVG(availability_percentage),2)
FROM dashboard.availability
WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-04-01'
GROUP BY availability_date
ORDER BY availability_date ASC
```

Then this is the one I'm using to get the data on the month of April:

```
SELECT availability_date, ROUND(AVG(availability_percentage),2)
FROM dashboard.availability
WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-05-01'
GROUP BY availability_date
ORDER BY availability_date ASC
```

Is it possible for me to combine them to one data so I can display the result on both month?
For example:

```
Month     percentage
March      100%
February   85%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(AVG(availability_percentage)
       FILTER (WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-04-01') , 2) AS avg_march,
    ROUND(AVG(availability_percentage)
       FILTER (WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-05-01'), 2) AS avg_april
FROM dashboard.availability
WHERE availability_date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-05-01';
```

Note that you should *not* be aggregating by date, because the averages you want to take span multiple dates.

Comment: This works if  I used GROUP BY. But I think i should remove the ORDER BY clause. Also how can i ROUND the result? It threw a massive amount of decimals but if i used the ROUND function it throws an error that "FILTER specified, but round is not an aggregate function"